# Algolia convert refinementList to selector

Tags: algolia

Hi guys so I'm trying to do a search in which I can filter through select inputs, not through checkboxes, its suppose to search only for just one filter at the time so checkboxes on a list will not do the trick as the widget throws it. Any Ideas?

Algolia is what I'm using for the instant search there is no changing that.

Currently I got:

[image]

And I am trying to get

[image]

Where you can only select one.

Comment: Would you be able to share a mock of your implementation with some comments?

Comment: @rayrutjes I updated the question with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable by using InstantSearch.js V2 and the connectors, have a look at the [customization guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/guides/customization.html). There's an example displaying a menu as a select box which is exactly what you would like to do. You can adapt it to refinementList and multiple selects.